# Wordpress Ensure text remains visible during webfont load

Tags: wordpress

Hi sorry for the bad english

I have a question so someone ask me to check a website using google insight and it gave me this
[image]

so the google insight have a solution to put "font-display: swap" but the website has a lot of plugins and i cant find where to put the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this as a CSS property or add to the of the URL when importing your google fonts, see below for examples:

In CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Or when importing:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```